# FireFox & Chrome CSS Differs

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, alignment, padding

The problem is, the CSS of site is different on FireFox and Chrome..

Fire fox loads it the way i want, but in chrome its messed up ...

I tried adding this to CSS as well,

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Im using Visual Studio 2010 so the site is on my localhost...

I tried clearing all cookies/cache...

Tried with a different Chrome based browser.. (SW Iron)... seems to be the same...

This is where the problem is coming..

```
.categories ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width:100%;
}

.categories ul li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    padding-top:10px;
}


.categories ul li:nth-child(1) a{
  padding: 0 66.5px 10px 66.5px;
  margin-left:16.375px;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(4) a{
  padding: 0 69px 10px 69px;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(6) a:after{
  display:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(7) a{
  margin-left:15.375px;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(8) a{
  padding: 0 51px 10px 51px;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(10) a{
  padding: 0 73px 10px 73px;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(11) a:after{
  display:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(12) a{
  margin-left:16.375px;
  padding: 0 53px 10px 53px;
  border-bottom:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(13) a{
  padding: 0 53px 10px 53px;
  border-bottom:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(14) a{
  border-bottom:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(15) a{
  padding: 0 53px 10px 53px;
  border-bottom:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(16) a{
  border-bottom:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(17) a:after{
  display:none;
}

.categories ul li:nth-child(17) a{
  border-bottom:none;
}


.categories ul li a {
   position : relative;
    float: left; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.categories ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, black, transparent);
}
 
 .categories ul li a:hover, .categories ul li .current 
 {
     
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.12) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.12))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.12) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.12) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.12) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.12) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#1fffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}
 
.categories ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```

[image: FireFox]

[image: Chrome]

Firefox image at top.... Chrome at bottom...

Comment: You went overboard with the CSS if that's the look you were going for. That could be achieved with a lot less.

Comment: Add this as the first style: `* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }` and then start styling from there.

Comment: @slime, Well i did it the way i knew :/
abhitalks i tried the code you gave, but no change... ?

Comment: Well in that case you have to create an MCVE for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, It is font rendering issue. The width of font is differant in `Chrome` & `Firefox`. Thus pixel required for same word are differant in `Firefox` & `Chrome`.

Along with that the technique you are using is fully wrong. Use are specifying width for each `li` by adjusting `padding`. *Instead give then equal width for each row. Thus there will be spare space to accomodate change in with of letters.*

Updated *generalized* code should look as follows:

```
/** General List Styles **/
ul{
    display: block;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:16.66%;
    position:relative;
}

li a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/** Middle Row Cell (Using 'middle' class on them) **/
li.middle{
    width:20%;
}

/** No Sep Cell (Using 'nosep:after' class on them) **/
li.nosep:after{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just give you the bare bones of what you're looking for:

```
ul {
    display: block;}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 50px;
    font-size: 14px;}

li:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3px;
    height: 10px;
    background: black;}

li:last-child:after {
    display: none;}
```

If you're just looking for them to stack naturally then you can just adjust the padding in the `li a` to modify the spacing, but if you're always looking for a certain amount per row, then add some percent widths to the `li` and if you wanted uneven numbers then that's when you target individual ones.